# Install modules to specific Python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm using **Python3** everyday for my personnal projects : Yesterday, I had to modify a web application using **Flask** and coded in **Python2.7**.
I installed Python2.7 but I didn't manage to install modules for this version.
I tried some commands like

```
C:\Python27>python -m pip install flask
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named pip
```

In PyCharm I set the Python2.7 interpreter which is in **C:\Python27**, and tried to install with the graphic interface :
[image: When trying to install flask in PyCharm]

I'm not a Python expert, so if you can help me to figure out and to resolve my issue ..

Thank you :)

Comment: you can just add the version to python and it will work like `python2.7 pip install module` but your problem seems to be different , you have to first install pip for python2.7

Comment: @PatrickDelaigle How come the question seems unrelated to the error message displayed? What have you tried to address the error in that message?

Answer (score 0):

First check if pip.exe is present in the installed python folder or not. In your case, check in the following folder "C:\Python27\Scripts" whether pip.exe or pip2.7.exe or pip2.exe are present.

If no, then first install pip by the following method:
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/

Now, after installation or already pip exists ensure to add the following path to environment variables; "C:\Python27\Scripts" and "C:\Python27\"
Refer https://gist.github.com/roblanf/6929493 for setting up environment variables

Comment: This is what I tried, you can see it on my previous screenshot